# preg_replace - remove link around image, wordpress post

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, preg-replace

Question is simple, how can I remove link around image with preg_replace ...

I need this to remove links from wordpress post with inserted image, manually will take to much time to remove all links from images.

Any help will be good, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using strip_tags() and set the allowable_tags to img

```
echo strip_tags($string, '<img>');
```